# Python - Tailing a logfile - sleep() versus inotify?

Tags: python, file-io, tail

I'm writing a Python script that needs to `tail -f` a logfile.

The operating system is RHEL, running Linux 2.6.18.

The normal approach I believe is to use an infinite loop with sleep, to continually poll the file.

However, since we're on Linux, I'm thinking I can also use something like pyinotify (https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) or Watchdog (https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) instead?

What are the pros/cons of the this?

I've heard that using `sleep()`, you can miss events, if the file is growing quickly - is that possible? I thought GNU tail uses sleep as well anyhow?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: GNU tail implementation - http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c Search for "inotify", they do seem to use it if available.

Comment: Note a third possible answer: `popen = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-f", filename])`.  Then use regular pipe reading methods on popen.stdout, for which you probably already have support, in your framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be inotify in many ways - this is more or less exactly what it's intended for, after all. If the log file was changing extremely rapidly then you could potentially risk being woken up almost constantly, which wouldn't necessarily be particularly efficient - however, you could always mitigate this by adding a short delay of your own after the inotify filehandle returns an event. In practice I doubt this would be an issue on most systems, but I thought it worth mentioning in case your system is very tight on CPU resources.

I can't see how the `sleep()` approach would miss file updates except in cases where the file is truncated or rotated (i.e. renamed and another file of the same name created). These are tricky cases to handle however you do things, and you can use tricks like periodically re-opening the file by name to check for rotation. Read the `tail` man page because it handles many such cases, and they're going to be quite common for log files in particular (log rotation being widely considered to be good practice).

The downside of `sleep()` is of course that you'd end up batching up your reads with delays in between, and also that you have the overhead of constantly waking up and polling the file even when it's not changing. If you did this, say, once per second, however, the overhead probably isn't noticeable on most systems.

I'd say inotify is the best choice unless you want to remain compatible, in which case the simple fallback using `sleep()` is still quite reasonable.

**EDIT:**

I just realised I forgot to mention - an easy way to check for a file being renamed is to perform an `os.fstat(fd.fileno())` on your open filehandle and a `os.stat()` on the filename you opened and compare the results. If the `os.stat()` fails then the error will tell you if the file's been deleted, and if not then comparing the `st_ino` (the inode number) fields will tell you if the file's been deleted and then replaced with a new one of the same name.

Detecting truncation is harder - effectively your read pointer remains at the same offset in the file and reading will return nothing until the file content size gets back to where you were - then the file will read from that point as normal. If you call `os.stat()` frequently you could check for the file size going backwards - alternatively you could use `fd.tell()` to record your current position in the file and then perform an explicit seek to the end of the file and call `fd.tell()` again. If the value is lower, then the file's been truncated under you. This is a safe operation as long as you keep the original file position around because you can always seek back to it after the check.

Alternatively if you're using inotify anyway, you could just watch the parent directory for changes.

Note that files can be truncated to non-zero sizes, but I doubt that's likely to happen to a log file - the common cases will be being deleted and replaced, or truncated to zero. Also, I don't know how you'd detect the case that the file was truncated and then immediately filled back up to beyond your current position, except by remembering the most recent N characters and comparing them, but that's a pretty grotty thing to do. I think inotify will just tell you the file has been modified in that case.